# Ubuntu 20.04 auto resetting Mouse

Tags: 20.04, usb, kernel, kubuntu, mouse

I have a Logitech bluetooth mouse. Since last month, it randomly stopped working every once in a while. If I unplugged and plugged it again, it would work for the next few minutes but eventually stopped as before. I thought the mouse went bad and bought a new wired one. A few days later, I faced the exact same issue. Looked up online and I did find similar issues but none of them were exactly like mine.

**Specs**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2
- Kernel: 5.4.0-80

**What I tried**

- Different USB 2.0/3.0 ports : Same issue
- Windows 10 : Same issue
- Different Mouse : Tried 4 mice so far. All 3 of them cause the exact same problem. (The last one hasn't exhibited any problem yet, but it's only been a day. First occurrence seems to take longer than the following ones)
- All the mouse work fine on different device.
- My keyboard and other USB devices work fine.

Here's what `dmesg` returns when the mouse stops responding:

````
usb 1-2: reset full-speed USB device number 75 using xhci_hcd
Jul 26 23:32:41 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172033.691650] usb 1-2: device firmware changed
Jul 26 23:32:41 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172033.691729] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 75
Jul 26 23:32:41 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172034.094450] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 76 using xhci_hcd
Jul 26 23:32:41 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172034.222720] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172034.452013] usb 1-2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172034.452022] usb 1-2: can't read configurations, error -71
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172034.578459] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 77 using xhci_hcd
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172034.727955] usb 1-2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172034.727963] usb 1-2: can't read configurations, error -71
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172034.728035] usb usb1-port2: attempt power cycle
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172035.142412] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172035.164385] usb 1-2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172035.164396] usb 1-2: can't read configurations, error -71
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172035.290538] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 79 using xhci_hcd
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172035.312117] usb 1-2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172035.312128] usb 1-2: can't read configurations, error -71
Jul 26 23:32:42 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172035.312214] usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
Jul 26 23:42:49 farhan-GL553VE-linux kernel: [172641.885177] mce: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, c```
````

Comment: *"Windows 10 : Same issue"* - this tells you that the problem has nothing to do with Ubuntu or Ubuntu software.  My guess?  Your USB bus/controller has a hardware fault.

Comment: I felt the same. But wasn't sure where exactly to post this. thanks. But what confuses me is, my other devices are working fine with the same ports. I was wondering how to explain this, if my usb bus/controller is faulty?